# Check if a query returns 4 sequential identical values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to check if there have been four identical values in a row (by which I mean one after the other, rather than in a table row) in MySQL. So, if I'm checking on the value "attachment", the following query result would be false:

```
type_count    post_type
1             post
2             attachment
3             post
4             post
5             attachment
6             post
7             attachment
8             post
9             post
10            post
11            post
12            attachment
13            post
14            post
15            post
```

Whereas this dataset would prove true:

```
type_count    post_type
1             post
2             attachment
3             post
4             post
5             attachment
6             attachment
7             attachment
8             attachment
9             post
10            post
11            post
12            attachment
13            post
14            post
15            post
```

Is this possible? Working from a query result rather than a table.

Comment: Are cursors and stored procedures accepted?

Comment: @cantSleepNow - Would rather do it with a query if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the query below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT type_count, post_type,
         @seq := IF(@pt = post_type, @seq+1,
                    IF(@pt := post_type, 1, 1)) AS seq
  FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @seq := 0, @pt := '') AS vars) AS t
WHERE post_type = 'attachment' AND seq >= 4
```

returns a number that is equal to or greater than 1, then your criteria is true, otherwise it is false.

If you're trying to find a sequence within a query result rather than a table, use a derived table, e.g `FROM (select * from table2) AS mytable`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `type_count` are continous you could use `EXIST` and simple `JOIN`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                         FROM mytable m1
                         JOIN mytable m2
                           ON m2.type_count = m1.type_count + 1
                         JOIN mytable m3
                           ON m3.type_count = m1.type_count + 2
                         JOIN mytable m4
                           ON m4.type_count = m1.type_count + 3
                         WHERE m1.post_type = 'attachment' 
                           AND m2.post_type = 'attachment' 
                           AND m3.post_type = 'attachment'
                           AND m4.post_type = 'attachment') 
             THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 END AS result
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/SOOXL14930)**</kbd><kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](http://rextester.com/XGC1027)**</kbd>

Output: 0 (false) and 1 (true)